# What is the URL of the site used by ExampleData?

Tags: curated-data, internet

When `ExampleData` is evaluated, *Mathematica* downloads data from a *Wolfram Research Data server*. What's the exact domain of this, though? I bet it's *something*.wolfram.com?

Comment: There is [ExampleData](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/note/ExampleDataSourceInformation.html) Source Information.

Comment: Any particular reason you're interested in this?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Honestly? I'd like to block this domain on my system so that I can get to work and not to play with these images ;P I'm serious now.

Comment: Try the function PacletSites[]

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries any idea what the local->false setting does?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), I was able see that `ExampleData` calls `pacletserver.wolfram.com`.

With Charles recording, I ran

```
ExampleData[{"Text", "AliceInWonderland"}]
```

and it gave me this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easy work around without needing to figure out URL
Remove all symbols used for retrieving example data from the Context

```
 Remove["DataPaclets`ExampleDataDump`*"]
```

This will permit you still to access the other Paclets data like for example CityData etc..

(PS: stop playing with the images now, hi,hi,hi)

Comment: if this works for you, vote for penguins....please.. hi,hi,hi